# TCP: When is EPOLLHUP generated?

Tags: linux, tcp, linux-kernel, epoll, epollet

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51833215/why-do-we-need-epollrdhup-when-epollhup-seems-enough), unanswered as of now.

There is a lot of confusion about `EPOLLHUP`, even in the `man` and Kernel docs. People seem to believe it is returned when polling on a descriptor *locally closed for writing*, i.e. `shutdown(SHUT_WR)`, i.e. the same call that causes an `EPOLLRDHUP` *at the peer*. But this is not true, in my experiments I get `EPOLLOUT`, and no `EPOLLHUP`, after `shutdown(SHUT_WR)` (yes, it's counterintuitive to get **writable**, as the writing half is closed, but this is not the main point of the question).

The [man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/epoll_ctl.2.html) is poor, because it says `EPOLLHUP` comes when *Hang up happened on the associated file descriptor*, without saying what "hang up" means - what did the peer do? what packets were sent? [This other article](https://lwn.net/Articles/519515/) just confuses things further and seems outright wrong to me.

My experiments show `EPOLLHUP` arrives once EOF (FIN packets) are exchanged both ways, i.e. once both sides issue `shutdown(SHUT_WR)`. It has nothing to do with `SHUT_RD`, which I never call. Also nothing to do with `close`. In terms of packets, I have the suspicion that `EPOLLHUP` is raised on the ack of the hosts' sent FIN, i.e. the termination initiator raises this event in step 3 of the 4-way shutdown handshake, and the peer, in step 4 (see [here](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPConnectionTermination-2.htm)). If confirmed, this is great, because it fills a gap that I've been looking for, namely how to poll non-blocking sockets for the final ack, without LINGER. **Is this correct?**

(note: I'm using ET, but I don't think it's relevant for this)

### Sample code and output.

The code being in a framework, I extracted the meat of it, with the exception of `TcpSocket::createListener`, `TcpSocket::connect` and `TcpSocket::accept`, which do what you'd expect (not shown here).

```cpp
void registerFd(int pollFd, int fd, const char* description)
{
    epoll_event ev = {
        EPOLLIN | EPOLLOUT | EPOLLRDHUP | EPOLLET,
        const_cast<char*>(description) // union aggregate initialisation, initialises first member (void* ptr)
    };
    epoll_ctl(pollFd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, fd, &ev);
}

struct EventPrinter
{
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const EventPrinter& obj)
    {
        return stream << "0x" << std::hex << obj.events_ << " = "
            << ((obj.events_& EPOLLIN) ? "EPOLLIN " : " ")
            << ((obj.events_& EPOLLOUT) ? "EPOLLOUT " : " ")
            << ((obj.events_& EPOLLERR) ? "EPOLLERR " : " ")
            << ((obj.events_& EPOLLRDHUP) ? "EPOLLRDHUP " : " ")
            << ((obj.events_& EPOLLHUP) ? "EPOLLHUP " : " ");
    }

    const uint32_t events_;
};

void processEvents(int pollFd)
{
    static int iterationCount = 0;
    ++iterationCount;

    std::array<epoll_event, 25> events;
    int eventCount;
    if (-1 ==
        (eventCount = epoll_wait(pollFd, events.data(), events.size(), 1)))
    {
        throw Exception("fatal: epoll_wait failed");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < eventCount; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "iteration #" << iterationCount << ": events on [" << static_cast<const char*>(events[i].data.ptr) << "]: [" << EventPrinter{events[i].events} << "]" << std::endl;
    }
}

TEST(EpollhupExample, SmokeTest)
{
    int pollFd_;
    if (-1 ==
        (pollFd_ = epoll_create1(0)))
    {
        throw Exception("fatal: could not create epoll socket");
    }

    const TcpSocket listener_ = TcpSocket::createListener(13500);
    if (!listener_.setFileStatusFlag(O_NONBLOCK, true))
        throw Exception("could not make listener socket non-blocking");
    registerFd(pollFd_, listener_.fd(), "listenerFD");

    const TcpSocket client = TcpSocket::connect("127.0.0.1", AF_INET, 13500);
    if (!client.valid()) throw;
    registerFd(pollFd_, client.fd(), "clientFD");





    //////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// start event processing ///////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////

    processEvents(pollFd_); // iteration 1

    const TcpSocket conn = listener_.accept();
    if (!conn.valid()) throw;
    registerFd(pollFd_, conn.fd(), "serverFD");

    processEvents(pollFd_); // iteration 2

    conn.shutdown(SHUT_WR);

    processEvents(pollFd_); // iteration 3

    client.shutdown(SHUT_WR);

    processEvents(pollFd_); // iteration 4
}
```

Output:

```
    Info| TCP connection established to [127.0.0.1:13500]
iteration #1: events on [listenerFD]: [1 = EPOLLIN     ]
iteration #1: events on [clientFD]: [4 =  EPOLLOUT    ]
    Info| TCP connection accepted from [127.0.0.1:35160]

iteration #2: events on [serverFD]: [4 =  EPOLLOUT    ]
    // calling serverFD.shutdown(SHUT_WR) here

iteration #3: events on [clientFD]: [2005 = EPOLLIN EPOLLOUT  EPOLLRDHUP  ]           // EPOLLRDHUP arrives, nice.
iteration #3: events on [serverFD]: [4 =  EPOLLOUT    ]                               // serverFD (on which I called SHUT_WR) just reported as writable, not cool... but not the main point of the question
    // calling clientFD.shutdown(SHUT_WR) here

iteration #4: events on [serverFD]: [2015 = EPOLLIN EPOLLOUT  EPOLLRDHUP EPOLLHUP ]   // EPOLLRDHUP arrives, nice. EPOLLHUP too!
iteration #4: events on [clientFD]: [2015 = EPOLLIN EPOLLOUT  EPOLLRDHUP EPOLLHUP ]   // EPOLLHUP on the other side as well. Why? What does EPOLLHUP mean actually?
```

There is not better way to rephrase the question, other than, **what does EPOLLHUP mean**? I made the case that [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/epoll_ctl.2.html) is poor, and information in other places (e.g. [here](https://lkml.org/lkml/2003/7/12/116) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51833215/why-do-we-need-epollrdhup-when-epollhup-seems-enough)) is wrong or useless.

**Note: To consider the Q answered, I want confirmation that EPOLLHUP is raised on the final FIN-ACKs of both directions.**

Comment: (note: this question is a re-post after adding clarifications and sample code, as requested by community members)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For these kind of questions, [use the source](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19/source/net/ipv4/tcp.c#L524)! Among other interesting comments, there is this text:

> `EPOLLHUP` is *UNMASKABLE* event (...). It means that after we received `EOF`, `poll` always returns immediately, making impossible `poll()` on `write()` in state `CLOSE_WAIT`. One solution is evident --- to set `EPOLLHUP` if and only if `shutdown` has been made in both directions.

And then the only code that sets `EPOLLHUP`:

```
if (sk->sk_shutdown == SHUTDOWN_MASK || state == TCP_CLOSE)
    mask |= EPOLLHUP;
```

Being `SHUTDOWN_MASK` equal to `RCV_SHUTDOWN |SEND_SHUTDOWN`.

TL; DR; You are right, this flag is only sent when the shutdown has been both for read and write (I reckon that the peer shutdowning the write equals to my shutdowning the read). Or when the connection is closed, of course.

**UPDATE**: From reading the source code with more detail, these are my conclusions.

About `shutdown`:

1. Doing `shutdown(SHUT_WR)` sends a `FIN` and marks the socket with `SEND_SHUTDOWN`.
2. Doing `shutdown(SHUT_RD)` sends nothing and marks the socket with `RCV_SHUTDOWN`.
3. Receiving a `FIN` marks the socket with `RCV_SHUTDOWN`.

And about `epoll`:

1. If the socket is marked with `SEND_SHUTDOWN` and `RCV_SHUTDOWN`, `poll` will return `EPOLLHUP`.
2. If the socket is marked with `RCV_SHUTDOWN`, `poll` will return `EPOLLRDHUP`.

So the `HUP` events can be read as:

1. `EPOLLRDHUP`: you have received `FIN` or you have called `shutdown(SHUT_RD)`. In any case your reading half-socket is hung, that is, you will read no more data.
2. `EPOLLHUP`: you have both half-sockets hung. The reading half-socket is just like the previous point, For the sending half-socket you did something like `shutdown(SHUT_WR)`.

To complete a a graceful shutdown I would do:

1. Do `shutdown(SHUT_WR)` to send a `FIN` and mark the end of sending data.
2. Wait for the peer to do the same by polling until you get a `EPOLLRDHUP`.
3. Now you can close the socket with grace.

**PS**: About your comment:

> it's counterintuitive to get writable, as the writing half is closed

It is actually expected if you understand the output of `epoll` not as *ready* but as *will not block*. That is, if you get `EPOLLOUT` you have the guarantee that calling `write()` will not block. And certainly, after `shutdown(SHUT_WR)`, `write()` will return immediately.

Comment: _I reckon that the peer shutdowning the write equals to my shutdowning the read_  No, you see, that is confusing. Why do you say that when there are 2 different things obviously: **receiving EPOLLRDHUP and shutdown(SHUT_RD)**.

Comment: ... the rest of what you say makes sense. But, from this: `RCV_SHUTDOWN |SEND_SHUTDOWN` I gather that in the kernel code you are pasting SHUTDOWN refers to receiving and sending FIN (NOT to SHUT_RD and SHUT_WR). SHUT_RD is bollocks, from what I can tell.

Comment: @haelix. My understanding is that calling `shutdown(SHUT_WR)` sends a `FIN` _and_ sets `SEND_SHUTDOWN`, calling `shutdown(SHUT_RD)` just sets `RCV_SHUTDOWN`, and getting a `FIN` from the peer also sets `RCV_SHUTDOWN`. And from the linked coude, see that you get a `EPOLLRDHUP` only when `RCV_SHUTDOWN` is set.

Comment: I understand, but I'm trying to highlight the (important, in my opinion) aspect that `EPOLLHUP` is generated as part of graceful shutdown. `SHUT_RD` is not graceful, it means "I'm refusing any more data", so the emphasis has to be on sending FIN **and receiving FIN** for the HUP to happen. I.e., the last paragraph in your Answer should be improved. If we are correct that is.

Comment: @haelix. I've browsed the source code a bit more and added my conclusions. Please, let me know if you agree.

Comment: Yep, it's good. Particularly the paragraph _To complete a a graceful shutdown I would do_. One last question, there is nothing in the sources about FIN ACKs? I was wondering also when do ACKs come into play. For example, if a FIN is not ACKed for a specific time, the FIN gets retransmitted - so I'm wondering if that still counts as `SEND_SHUTDOWN`.

Comment: @haelix: The retransmission code is complicated, the `FIN` code is complicated, the retransmission of `FIN`s is... well, very complicated. But I don't think it makes any difference to the `epoll` usage, because the `SEND_SHUTDOWN` flag is set as soon as `shutdown()` is called.